# Openvpn suddenly stopped working on some laptops in my college

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, openvpn

- My College: The LNM Institute of Information Technology
- What our tech department uses: Cyberaom Firewall for userid authentication

What we found out 3 months back: OpenVPN was our solution to everything even STEAM and Dota 2.

What happened 2 nights ago: Suddenly OpenVPN stops working and our of every 32 computers connected to the same LAN hub only 1 person can connect to OpenVPN. If he shuts down then also no one can connect. Only he and he can connect to OpenVPN.

Out of the 4 configs only UDP 53 runs in our college as the rest of the ports are blocked or the traffic is monitored. Every time I try connecting to any config I get a TLS handshake failed.

```
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 OpenVPN 2.3.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [IPv6] built on Mar 28 2013
Enter Management Password:
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25344
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25344
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sun Sep 01 19:54:40 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sun Sep 01 19:54:57 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'username "Auth" "vpnbook"'
Sun Sep 01 19:54:57 2013 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'password [...]'
Sun Sep 01 19:54:57 2013 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sun Sep 01 19:54:57 2013 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Sun Sep 01 19:54:57 2013 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are running on Windows
Sun Sep 01 19:54:58 2013 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sun Sep 01 19:54:58 2013 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun Sep 01 19:54:58 2013 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]93.115.84.195:53
Sun Sep 01 19:54:58 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1378045498,WAIT,,,
Sun Sep 01 19:55:21 2013 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Sun Sep 01 19:55:21 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1378045521,EXITING,SIGTERM,,
```

The above log is of UDP 53, Euro 1 server attempt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The same is going on in our "College". Nothing works here, TOR, publicly known proxies like those introduced by HideMyAss network, 95% of web proxies. Try [VPN Gate](http://www.vpngate.net/en/)

Comment: One computer in each hostel wing is able to connect but the rest are not. If the college tech had done something it would stop for everyone but how come it stops for us and not those machines.

Comment: I don't remember exactly the name of the software (cyber something) that our college used, but the last time I checked their scary network, they had assigned each freaking device in our campus a sort of ID, in fact the whole university is like that. They could determine who could connect to what. That was why some of our professors had access to almost any website (even porn sites), but some didn't. They even kept log of our activities. Any hows I don't know what is going on over your place, if staff is "student-friendly"! go talk to them, or sick with VPN Gate, it works very fine.

Comment: I think it was CyberPatrol.

Comment: You will be surprised to know that VPN Gate configs are not working. Obviously now i can explain that something has changed in the internal routing of our college. But still cannot figure how it works on specific laptops :(